# HTML/CSS3 Border-Radius Issue in jQuery Slider

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having a issue in a Content Slider that when I scroll (by clicking on 1,2,3,4,5-NAV) the content is not appearing properly in corners. I have used border-radius CSS but it's not working during the animation.

See Here:

http://optimaww.com/agendabe/

Comment: Please post the relevant code within your question so that it's useful for future readers.  See http://sscce.org

Comment: @Sparky672: Sorry I can't post the code here, its a long code and the website is dynamic and the issue can be resolved by CSS, please check here: http://optimaww.com/agendabe/  (In Chrome).

Comment: Now that you've fixed your problem, nobody else will be able to learn anything by reading this page.  That's really a selfish way to use StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One part of the issue is to remove `background:white` from `.slide_01_text` and give it to its parent element. Now you still have to deal with images. Try to use the images as a `background-image` and give the `<li>` the same `border-radius` as its parent. That should do it.

Comment: Thanks for answer, 1st point helped me 100%, but still i am having issue with image, i can't use the image as background-image as it will be a dynamic image in every slide! Please help

Comment: You can still use background-image within the style attribute `<li style="background-image:...`

Comment: Frank, I can't use background-image, client has said that he wants "<img src="" ...." tag. Is there any other way to sort out this issue.

Comment: Don't think so. Your client is sticking his nose too much in your business.